# GCP forgotten email address used for account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Please how can one know which email address i used for opening a GCP account based on the server IP ? I registered a GCP account months ago but can't remember which email was used.

Comment: pradeep's answer is good. Most likely you created the GCP account using a Google Gmail address. Go to this link. Most likely your accounts are remembered: https://accounts.google.com/servicelogin

Comment: Another idea is to go to your home directory on a computer that you previously SSH'd into the GCE instance. Look in the directory `.ssh`. If you see a file named `google_compute_engine.pub`, look at the bottom of the file. That contains part of the username used to SSH which often is close to the GCP account email.

Comment: I opened the GCP account using a gmail address, if i can't remember that email address, there is no way i can even login to the server. All the time i ssh into the server was via the GCP ssh link that opens a browser instance.

Answer (score 3):

If you can login to the server and that server has permissions to query IAM then you can list all the IAM members of the project. From the list you can infer which email you used.

If you can login to the server in a GCP Project then you can run following to get the project id:

```
curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"  "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id"
```

Then,You can run

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy YOUR_GCP_PROJECT_ID
```

Also, if you remember the credentials of other gmail account which you mentioned in comment, you can login with those credentials to GCP Console and then look all the members in IAM section.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since am not able to login, there is no way i can get the project ID. Any advise please?

Comment: Can you login to the server you mentioned in the question?

Comment: I can login to a different server on GCP created using different gmail account.

Comment: If everything else fails you will have to contact GCP support and provide evidence that you are the owner of the project (which might include but is not limited to show invoices, ownership of the gmail account, etc)

Comment: how can i contact that i will get fast response please ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but for those finding themselves in a situation where you are, best case scenario, simply trying to figure out which one of you accounts is the Super Admin over your GCP and attached projects without terminal access... go through each of you Gmail accounts that may be culprits and go to your payment information. Assuming you have enabled paid features and have not changed/re-assigned the billing administrator for your GCP projects, the GCP owner account should have the billing information in the payments page including GCP ORG/Account ID as well as the debit/credit card attached; payments.google.com is where you want to check.

> Note: It doesn't matter if you haven't actually made a single payment yet and have been living of the land and the 300$ sign-on credit, as long as there's a card configed to take payment, you should have found your account.

Also, consider filtering emails to all your google accounts for emails from "payments-noreply@google.com" or "CloudPlatform-noreply@google.com.

Finding which is which shouldn't be a problem as long as you have access to said google/gmail account. If you happed to have lost, forgotten the account ... consider email filtering the title "Someone added you as their recovery email" in your main email which you most likely used as a recovery method.

If you did not set this up, nor a phone number for recovery then your one and only hope is to start the "Assisted" recovery process where you will be asked to enter an email you own, enter an OTP they provide via email, and give them 48 hours. When doing so, use the same device, browser, and location to increase the odds that they will be able to do anything for you... god speed ya'll